# estoy tratando de crear un proyecto pero me sale este error NoSuchMethod Error The method '[]' null. online

Tags: flutter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo este problema medice que [] en online es nulo

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Tengo este código pero tengo un problema cuando compiló la aplicación  en el emulador me dice que  online: json [online] es un método nulo?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que validar si json es nulo antes de asignar los valores a las propiedades de tu clase Usuario en factory Usuario.fromJson, hay varias formas una es

`online: json['online'] != null ? json['online] : ''`

también puedes declarar las propiedades de la clase usuario como nullable, utilizando  el símbolo `?` después del tipo, ej: `bool? online` (para esto tienes que utilizar Dart >= 2.12 en tu pubspec.yaml)

`online: json['online'] != null ? json['online] : null`